# search multiple partial matches on same column in SQL using parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get some data using parameters on my query, but the problem is that these parameters are just a part of the content.

my table would be something like the following:

```
  |columnName
1 | AAA-XX
2 | AAA-YY
3 | AAA-ZZ
4 | BBB-BB
5 | BBB-CC
6 | BBB-11
5 | CCC-AA
6 | DDD-FF
```

the problem is that my application only knows the part before the "-", so I have a list like ["AAA", "DDD"]. I am able to use "like" to get one parameter, but I need to use a list of them dynamically.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE columnName like '@[names]%'
```

where names = ["AAA", "DDD"] and get the result like this:

```
  |columnName
1 | AAA-XX
2 | AAA-YY
3 | AAA-ZZ
4 | DDD-FF
```

Just to clarify, the list names changes all the time (it might be ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD"] or even ["CCC"]) depending on my application needs so a hardcoded solution won't work for me.

My application is built on C# and the request is bult using DynamicParameters.Add("@[names]", names, DbType.string), this way the only thing I know of is the query string, I cannot pass any hardcoded parameters to it.

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  How are you passing in the values?  SQL does not (generally) have a built-in array datatype.

Comment: Pass a comma delimited string and parse it out into a table and say where columnName in (select name from commaseperatedtablevalues).  

Since I dont know what sql technology you are using I cant give you code example

Comment: the request comes from my app built in C#. I normally pass a list using @[listName] on my query and add the values using DyniamicParameters.Add("@[listName]", listName, DbType.string)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `OR`.

```
SELECT columnname
       FROM elbat
       WHERE columnname LIKE '<value_1>%'
             ...
              OR columnname LIKE '<value_n>%';
```

For `'AAA'` and `'DDD'` that would look like:

```
SELECT columnname
       FROM elbat
       WHERE columnname LIKE 'AAA%'
              OR columnname LIKE 'DDD%';
```

Or join a `VALUES` clause with the names.

```
SELECT elbat.columnname
       FROM elbat
            INNER JOIN (VALUES ('<value_1>'),
                               ...
                               ('<value_n>')) names (name)
                       ON elbat.columnname LIKE concat(names.name, '%');
```

Again for `'AAA'` and `'DDD'` that would look like:

```
SELECT elbat.columnname
       FROM elbat
            INNER JOIN (VALUES ('AAA'),
                               ('DDD')) names (name)
                       ON elbat.columnname LIKE concat(names.name, '%');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=219b68ac8eb33d82bef6555ddfb98a8a)

Comment: @DaniloRibeiro: Of course you'd have construct the queries depending on the values. The queries I showed are just *examples* of how such a query could look like for the example values you gave. They're not meant to be "hardcoded". I edited the answer to point that out a little more.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp
( columnname varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp values ('AAA-XX'), ('AAA-YY'), ('AAA-ZZ'), ('BBB-BB'), ('BBB-CC'), ('BBB-11'), ('CCC-AA'),  ('DDD-FF')

declare @string varchar(50) = 'AAA,BBB,CCC';

SELECT *
FROM #temp t
   JOIN string_split (@string, ',') s
      on columnname like s.value + '%'
```

You may also use Substring if you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp t
   JOIN string_split (@string, ',') s
      on s.value  = SUBSTRING (columnname, 1, CHARINDEX('-', columnname) - 1)
```